# Smooth animation of the search bar and the dropdown list along with it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm trying to achieve smooth animation of searchbar (MUI Autocomplete). This should work only on Smartphones (Screen < 600px).

Here is an example (it is very buggy and open it on smartphone to see the animation): https://react-zxuspr-gjq5w8.stackblitz.io/

And here is my implementation, but I've a few problems with that:

1. The interval does not reset on dropdown close.

   - The `React.useEffect()` dependency is set to `searchActive`, which is changed dynamically.
   - I tried calling the callback function of `React.useState()`, but since the component is not destroyed, I am not sure if it makes sense.
2. The width of dropdown, which is also changed in the `setInterval()` function, is not smooth at all.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zxuspr-gjq5w8?file=demo.js

Here is part of the component where the logic is implemented:

```
export function PrimarySearchAppBar() {
  const [searchActive, setSearchActive] = React.useState(null);
  const [acPaperWidth, setAcPaperWidth] = React.useState(null);
  const [acPaperTransX, setAcPaperTransX] = React.useState(0);

  const AcRef = React.useRef(null);
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(useTheme().breakpoints.down('sm'));

  const options = top100Films.map((option) => {
    const group = option.group.toUpperCase();
    return {
      firstLetter: group,
      ...option,
    };
  });

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (AcRef.current) {
      setAcPaperWidth(AcRef.current.offsetWidth);
    }
    console.log(acPaperWidth);
  }, [AcRef]);

  let interval;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (searchActive) {
      if (acPaperTransX <= 39) {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
          setAcPaperWidth(AcRef.current.offsetWidth);
          setAcPaperWidth((acPaperTransX) => acPaperTransX + 1);
          if (acPaperTransX >= 38) {
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
          console.log(acPaperTransX);
        }, 10);
      }
    } else {
      setAcPaperTransX(0);
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [searchActive]);

  return (
    <>Hello World</>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `interval` variable was defined outside the `React.useEffect()` hook, so its value was not preserved on re-renders.

I was able to fix that by using `React.useRef()`:

```
const intervalRef = React.useRef();
const acPaperTransXRef = React.useRef(acPaperTransX);
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (searchActive) {
    if (acPaperTransXRef.current <= 39) {
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setAcPaperWidth(AcRef.current.offsetWidth);
        acPaperTransXRef.current += 0.1;
        if (acPaperTransXRef.current >= 38) {
          clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
          acPaperTransXRef.current = 0;
        }
        console.log(acPaperTransXRef.current);
      }, 2);
    }
  } else {
    setAcPaperTransX(0);
    acPaperTransXRef.current = 0;
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }
  return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
}, [searchActive]);
```